# Simian not detecting duplicate code in CruiseControl.Net integration

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, simian

My Simian task looks like this:

```
<exec>
<executable>C:\\Program Files (x86)\simian\bin\simian-2.3.33.exe</executable>
<buildArgs>-includes=*.cs -formatter=xml:build\log\simian.xml-failOnDuplication</buildArgs>
</exec>
```

The build log looks like this:

```
<simian version="2.3.33">
    <check failOnDuplication="true" ignoreCharacterCase="true" ignoreCurlyBraces="true" ignoreIdentifierCase="true" ignoreModifiers="true" ignoreStringCase="true" threshold="6">
        <summary duplicateFileCount="0" duplicateLineCount="0" duplicateBlockCount="0" totalFileCount="0" totalRawLineCount="0" totalSignificantLineCount="0" processingTime="94"/>
    </check>
</simian>
```

I know the solution has duplicate code, so I guess I'm missing something, any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`totalFileCount="0"`** points to Simian not finding any files. Try running it like this (I'm guessing CruiseControl.Net is doing some needless escaping on your command line):

```xml
<exec>
  <executable>C:\\Program Files (x86)\simian\bin\simian-2.3.33.exe</executable>
  <buildArgs>-includes=**/*.cs -formatter=xml:build\log\simian.xml -failOnDuplication</buildArgs>
</exec>
```

Another important difference in this syntax is `-includes=**/*.cs`, which instructs Simian to include subdirectories in file search.

Comment: Using this configuration I get this in Event Viewer: Service cannot be started. ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Config.ConfigurationException: Unused node detected: <arg value="-formatter=xml:build\log\simian.xml" />

Comment: Not sure if that configuration represents a Nant exec task. I am using Cruise Control exec blocks

Comment: Updated, previous syntax was for NAnt.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought so. I have already tried the -includes=**/*.cs syntax, and still get totalFileCount="0". I suppose the question is how does Simian determine the base directory to recurse from.

Comment: You can set `<baseDirectory>`, but it should already point to your project working dir. Try setting the log level in ccnet service configuration file to `DEBUG` and check what actual parameters are passed to Simian.